# SQL calculate Datediff for half of the 8 working day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to compare 2 dates and return the number of days in between. Here is a table as example:

```
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | userid |       datestarted       |     datefinished        |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|    |        |                         |                         |
|  1 |     23 | 2014-03-25 09:05:00.000 | 2014-03-25 12:15:00.000 |
|  2 |     43 | 2014-03-25 09:05:00.000 | 2014-03-25 12:15:00.000 |
|  3 |     23 | 2014-03-31 09:05:00.000 | 2014-03-31 12:15:00.000 |
|  4 |     12 | 2014-03-25 09:05:00.000 | 2014-03-26 12:15:00.000 |
+----+--------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

In the first 3 cases, we have the same day, only the hours don't match.

```
Datestarted = 2014-03-25 09:05:00.000

Datefinished = 2014-03-25 12:15:00.000
```

We only input `hours` and `minutes`.

Until now, wee needed only to show the `difference` as `whole number`, without `decimal points`, and did it like this:

```
DATEDIFF(carsharing.datestarted, carsharing.datefinished)
```

But now, we have to show the `difference` between the dates as `0,5 day`, if it is `less` than `4,5 hours`. If the difference is `greater` it should stay as `1 day`.

In the more complecated last case from the table, we should also compare and show difference between two different days

```
Datestarted = 2014-03-25 09:05:00.000

Datefinished = 2014-03-26 12:15:00.000
```

Here the result should be `1,5 days`

Comment: Edit your question with sample data in a tabular format, along with desired results.  The logic is hard to follow.

Comment: Have you considered writing a CLR function in C# to expose your answer in the form of a TimeSpan, which could then be formatted as a result in the format of days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds?

Comment: DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query. It gets the difference in minutes and multiply it by 2 in order to get a 0.5 day range. It then devide it by 24 hours and by 60 minutes before calculating the Ceiling value. Once you have it, it can be devide by 2 again.

When the value is over 4.5*24*60 (4.5 days in minutes), it only has to be devided by 24 and 60.

> **Query:**

```
Select id, userid, datestarted, datefinished
    , Days = Case When DATEDIFF(minute, datestarted, datefinished) > 4.5*60*24      
        then DATEDIFF(minute, datestarted, datefinished) / 24 / 60
        else CEILING(((2.0*DATEDIFF(minute, datestarted, datefinished)) / 24 / 60)) / 2
    end
From @dates
```

> **Output:**

```
id  userid  datestarted                 datefinished                Days
1   23      2014-03-25 09:05:00.000     2014-03-25 12:15:00.000     0.500000
2   43      2014-03-25 09:05:00.000     2014-03-25 12:15:00.000     0.500000
3   23      2014-03-31 09:05:00.000     2014-03-31 12:15:00.000     0.500000
4   12      2014-03-25 09:05:00.000     2014-03-26 12:15:00.000     1.500000
5   12      2014-03-25 09:05:00.000     2014-03-29 12:15:00.000     4.500000
6   12      2014-03-25 09:05:00.000     2014-03-29 22:15:00.000     4.000000
```

> **Sample Data**

```
declare @dates table(id int, userid int, datestarted datetime, datefinished datetime);
insert into @dates(id, userid, datestarted, datefinished) values
(1, 23, '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-25 12:15:00.000')
, (2, 43, '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-25 12:15:00.000')
, (3, 23, '2014-03-31 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-31 12:15:00.000')
, (4, 12, '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-26 12:15:00.000')
, (5, 12, '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-29 12:15:00.000')
, (6, 12, '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000', '2014-03-29 22:15:00.000')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for - this will round the difference to 0.5 for anything under 4.5 hours in the day, and everything else over that will go to a full day:

```
Declare @StartDate  DateTime = '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000',
        @EndDate    DateTime = '2014-03-26 12:15:00.000'

;With TotalHours As
(
    Select  DateDiff(Minute, @StartDate, @EndDate) / 60.0 As TotalHours
)
Select  Case 
            When TotalHours % 24 = 0
                Then Floor(TotalHours / 24)
            When TotalHours % 24 < 4.5 
                Then Floor(TotalHours / 24) + 0.5 
            Else Floor(TotalHours / 24) + 1.0
        End As Days
From    TotalHours
```

Comment: It's hard to keep track with all your revisions you're making at the moment, but at the time of writing this comment there's a problem in your boundary checks. To see what I mean - change the times to exactly the same, one day apart - you get 1.5 days returned instead of 1.0

Comment: @Bridge Thanks for pointing that out - corrected it for that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE 
    @StartDate datetime = '2014-03-25 09:05:00.000'
    ,@EndDate datetime = '2014-03-26 09:05:00.000'
;WITH d AS (SELECT DATEDIFF(d,@StartDate,@EndDate) Dys) 
,h AS (SELECT DATEDIFF(hh,@StartDate,@EndDate) Hrs)
SELECT d.Dys + CASE WHEN (h.Hrs - d.Dys*24) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN (h.Hrs - d.Dys*24) < 4.5 THEN 0.5 ELSE 1 END END
FROM d,h
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - I checked with dates 23:59:00 apart (e.g. set your second time to '2014-03-26 09:04:00.000') it returns 1.5 days when it's actually less than 1.0

Comment: @Bridge - I have modified it. If you want the calculations to be more accurate, like including minutes, let me know. I will modify the query.